# Como colocar variáveis em email com o phpMailer?

Tags: php, variáveis, phpmailer

```
$sql = ("SELECT nome, datas FROM tabelas WHERE datediff(now(), data) <= 10 ");
$validade = mysql_query($sql);

while....
(codigo phpmailer)
// corpo da mensagem
$PHPMailer->Body = "<p>Faltam 10 dias ou menos para terminar a data do Documento  ".$Nome."</p>";
```

Necessito que na mensagem ele me mostre o Nome e a data que está com menos de 10 dias para terminar que está inserido na BD.

Tentei testar só com o nome e também não funciona.

```
$PHPMailer->Body = "<p>Faltam 10 dias ou menos para terminar a data do Documento ".$Nome."</p>";
```

Comment: O nome vem em branco ou o html não é exibido?

Comment: Poderia por favor deixar mais clara sua pergunta? Nã está claro se o problema é de SQL ou de PHP.

Comment: Se puder, coloque como está tratando o retorno da consulta. Muitas vezes pode ser uma variável nula ou não inicializada. Usar o **error_reporting(E_ALL)** é uma boa alternativa pra prevenir que erros passem despercebidos.

Comment: Verifique se a consulta está retornando alguma coisa; Faça um teste separado; Você pode colocar valores dinâmicos a vontade. Basta usar como você está fazendo ou inserir {} na variável ('{$nome}').

Comment: O nome fica em branco . peço '.$Nome.' e mostra-me '..'

Comment: @user3253195 Dá para colocar a consulta completa que está a ser realizada? Não dá para saber se os campos que estás a tentar utilizar efectivamente são recolhidos na consulta. Por outro lado, como é que da consulta até chegar à variável `$Nome` estás a trabalhar os dados?

Comment: Mas ao pedir na query nomes e datas não consigo ir buscar o nome? Já actualizo

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está na query. Não é assim que se faz calculo com datas em MySQL/MariaDB. Repare que você está somando um inteiro, mas não diz o que esse inteiro é. O banco de dados nesse caso tem uma sintaxe que explicita que tipo de intervalo é, no caso o `INTERVAL`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela 
   WHERE data < (NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY) ## data menor que (agora + 10 dias)
         AND data > NOW() ## e maior que agora
```

Por favor, veja essa tabela que fala sobre calculo de data com `INTERVAL` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0):

O Nome e Data que você deseja mostra devem estar na sua busca.

```
select nome, data from ...
```

Sua dúvida não parece ser sobre o phpMailer e sim sobre como consultar dados. Por favor, detalhe melhor a estrutura da sua tabela e qual SGDB.