# Como enviar uma pagina PHP completa por email ??

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5

Estou com problemas para enviar um template de e-mail.
Tenho a Seguinte pagina :

```
<?php session_start();  ?>
```

Contato - PiscouAchou


    
        
            
            Email enviado com sucesso !

```
    <section id="conteudo">
        <p>
            Obrigado por utilizar o contato Piscou achou, o estabelecimento já ira entrar em contato com você.</br></br>

            Caso queira um contato mais direto visite a pagina www.piscouachou.com.br
            e clique em ver telefone na pagina do estabelecimento.</br></br>

            Estabelecimento: <?php echo $_SESSION['nomeE']; ?></br>
            ID: Estabelecimento: <?php echo $_SESSION['idE']; ?>
        </p>
    </section>

    <section id="imagem">
        <img src="img/separador.png" alt="">
    </section>

    <div id="public">
    <section id="estabelecimento">
        <h2>· Estabelecimento ·</h2>
        <h4>Ainda não é assinante?</h4>
        <p>
            Entre em contato:</br>

            email: contato@piscouachou.com.br</br>
            telefone: 11 4107-5077
            </br>
            </br>
        </p>
        <a href="http://www.piscouachou.com.br/contato.php" class="css_btn_class">Piscou Achou</a>
       </section>

    <section id="grupoemais">
        <h2>· Grupo Emais·</h2>
        <h4>Conhece nossos serviços?</h4>
        <p>
            Grupo Emais é composto por 4 empresas que oferecem suporte às corporações
            em tudo o que diz respeito à comunicação.
            </br>
            </br>
        </p>
        <a href="http://www.grupoemais.com.br/" class="css_btn_class2">Grupo Emais</a>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estava tentando dar include dessa pagina em uma pagina com os valores da $_SESSION atualizados, mas quando envio o e-mail as imagens não aparecerem e os valores da SESSION não funcionam.

Estou utilizando PHPMAILER.

```
$Vdata = file_get_contents('EmailEmais');
$mail -> body = $Vdata;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível mandar uma página PHP por email, você pode enviar o HTML gerado a partir dela.

para enviar HTML você faz :

```
include_once("geradorHtml.php");

$geradorDeHtml = new Gerador();

$html = $geradorDeHtml->geraHtml($_SESSION['nomeE'],$_SESSION['idE']);
$mail->MsgHTML($html);
$mail->IsHtml(true);
```

E no documento **geradorHtml.php** :

```
 class Gerador {
    public function geraHtml($nome,$id){


    $html = ' <section id="conteudo">
        <p>
            Obrigado por utilizar o contato Piscou achou, o estabelecimento já ira entrar em contato com você.</br></br>

            Caso queira um contato mais direto visite a pagina www.piscouachou.com.br
            e clique em ver telefone na pagina do estabelecimento.</br></br>

            Estabelecimento:'.$nome.'</br>
            ID: Estabelecimento:'.$id.'
        </p>
    </section>

    <section id="imagem">
        <img src="img/separador.png" alt="">
    </section>

    <div id="public">
    <section id="estabelecimento">
        <h2>· Estabelecimento ·</h2>
        <h4>Ainda não é assinante?</h4>
        <p>
            Entre em contato:</br>

            email: contato@piscouachou.com.br</br>
            telefone: 11 4107-5077
            </br>
            </br>
        </p>
        <a href="http://www.piscouachou.com.br/contato.php" class="css_btn_class">Piscou Achou</a>
       </section>

    <section id="grupoemais">
        <h2>· Grupo Emais·</h2>
        <h4>Conhece nossos serviços?</h4>
        <p>
            Grupo Emais é composto por 4 empresas que oferecem suporte às corporações
            em tudo o que diz respeito à comunicação.
            </br>
            </br>
        </p>
        <a href="http://www.grupoemais.com.br/" class="css_btn_class2">Grupo Emais</a>
    </section>
    </div>
</div>';


    return $html;

    }


    }
```

Comment: Eu colocaria o EmailEmais.php no $nome ??

Comment: Não, dentro dessa função `geraHtml()`, na variável `$html` você coloca o seu texto HTML, e passa como parâmetro pra função o que vai substituir as variáveis no seu HTML, por exemplo : `$_SESSION['nomeE']` , desta forma você não fica tão dependente da session

Comment: @KaueAlves Editei

Comment: Muito Obrigado consegui aqui !!

Answer (score 0):

Provavelemtne seu problem esta em usar SESSION. Ele deve retornar o valor de SESSION nulo durante o envio.

Ou você usaria dados gerados dinamicamente por consultas. O que seria um pouco custoso para o envio de email, ou podes tentar gerar HTML estático com um scritp que pré-processas estas páginas que vocÊ precisa enviar, inserindo as variáveis.

[Como colocar variáveis em email com o phpMailer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093/como-colocar-vari%C3%A1veis-em-email-com-o-phpmailer)

Minha sugestão é que você gere essas páginas, que vai usar no email, com um  pré-processador, para gerar esta página estática, em HTML mesmo. Assim seus emails irão corretamente.

Ou, por fim, você pode tentar gerar o html dinamicamento com seu script de envio de email. Cria uma classe só pra gerar o html, com strings. E passa essa variável como body do teu email.

http://recursosdophp.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/criar-um-arquivo-html-com-php.html